# Multivariable calculus open set question 1

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, continuity

Given $[A=\left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x^3y^3>x^2+y^2 \right \}]$,
Prove that $A$ is an open set by proving that $[A^c]$ is a closed set.

Comment: The tag *continuity* makes this question really awkward since it hints at a particular way of showing $A^c$ is closed, which is pretty much the same as showing directly that $A$ is open.

Comment: Why prove it in such a roundabout way. It is easier to show that $A$ is open; it follows immediately from continuity of $f(x,y) = x^3y^3 - x^2 -y^2$. Consider $(p_{1},p_{2}) \equiv p \in A$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $||q-p||<\delta$ (use Euclidean norm), we have $|f(q)-f(p)|< f(p)/2$ which implies $f(q) > f(p) - f(p)/2 = f(p)/2 > 0$. But then $f(q) \in A$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement is the graph of $x^3 y^3 \ge x^2+y^2$, or of $x^3y^3 - x^2-y^2\ge 0$.  If you know that $(x,y)\mapsto x^3y^3 - x^2-y^2$ is continuous and that $[0,\infty)$ is a closed set, then that tells you the graph is the inverse-image of a closed set under a continuous function, hence it is a closed set.

Alternatively, you could say that $A$ itself is the inverse-image of the open set $(-\infty,0)$ under the same continuous function, and inverse-images of open sets under continuous functions are open.